# More tag and featured image

Tags: post-thumbnails

i'm a rookie on wordpress, but it's working out quiet nice but I've a questions..
Is it possible to use More Tag in your post and still display your featured image?
Only when I click on it to reveal the full post it will display the featured image?

Are there ways to do it or not? Hope you can help me out!

Answer (score 0):

The featured image will only be shown before the more tag if your theme is setup to display it that way. If you want to do this manually, you will have to insert the image before the more tag yourself in the WYSIWYG editor, just as you would add any other image into the content.

The other option is to change your theme to include the featured image programatically but this may be more of a challenge if you are unfamiliar with the PHP code required to do this.